Uniformly sampling a random 3 qubit clifford gate
I try to uniformly sample 3 qubit clifford gates and apply them to my circuit. I'm using python language. I'm following this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406196 (Supplementary Materials 1.Methods section A).  In this paper, one considers a N-qubit unitary gate $U$ as a $2N*2N$ matrix with the first N colomns as the image of $X_{1}...X_{N}$ under $U$ and the rest as the images of $Z_{1}...Z_{N}$ under $U$. And the entries are binary numbers 0 or 1. The problem is that I do not know what is the most efficient way to do this numerically or whether the output from qiskit or stim matches my desired format ($2N*2N$ matrix). Could someone give me some guidance? Thank you so much !

Sounds like you want stim.Tableau.random and stim.Tableau.to_numpy.

Thanks. I would like to take a look at these.
